# Tablesorter configuration headers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is there a way to configure tablesorter headers by ids or classes instead of column number?

So instead of this:

```
headers:
          { 0: { sorter: 'digit' } ,
        1: { sorter: false  } 
}
```

I'd like to do it like this:

```
'some class or id': { sorter: 'digit' } ,
'some class or id': { sorter: false  }
```

And the same for sorting

```
[[0,0],[1,0]] => would be [['some class',0],['some id',0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do exactly that (would have been perfect for what I needed if I could) but this worked for me - http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-headers.html

Note that the demo on that page doesn't actually work, but when I also included the MetaData plugin (jquery.metadata.js - included in the download) and added the `class="{sorter: false}"` to the heading it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you are below plugin, check the configuration documentation.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

If you are using some other plugin try checking the documentation. Hope it helps!